Is this monoid generated from lines in $\mathbb{R}^d$ cancellative and torsion-free?
Let $L^d = \{\mathbb{R}v \ : \ v \in \mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\}\}$ denote the set of lines through the origin of the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^d$. I am interested in a commutative monoid generated by $L^d$. Specifically, let $M^d$ be the commutative monoid with generators $[\ell]$ for each $\ell \in L^d$ subject to the relations
$$
 [\ell_1] + [\ell_2] = [\ell_3] + [\ell_4]
$$
for all $\ell_1, \dots, \ell_4 \in L^d$ such that

$\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ span the same $2$-plane as $\ell_3$ and $\ell_4$, and
$\ell_1 \perp \ell_2$ and $\ell_3 \perp \ell_4$, that is, $\ell_1$ is orthogonal to $\ell_2$ and $\ell_3$ to $\ell_4$ with respect to the standard inner product of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Example: If $d = 2$, then we consider all lines in the plane. Each line $\ell$ has a unique perpendicular line $\ell^\perp$ and we have that $[\mathbb{R}^2] := [\ell_1] + [\ell_1^\perp] = [\ell_2] + [\ell_2^\perp]$ for all $\ell_1, \ell_2 \in L^2$. Thus every element $a \in M^2$ can be written uniquely as
$$ a \ = \ k_0 [\mathbb{R}^2] + k_1 [\ell_1] + k_2 [\ell_2] + \dots + k_r [\ell_r]\,,$$
where $k_0, k_1, \dots, k_r \geq 0$ are integers and the $\ell_1, \dots, \ell_r$ are pair-wise non-orthogonal.
I have the following questions:

Is the monoid $M^d$ cancellative, that is, does $a + c = b + c$ in $M^d$ imply $a = b$?
Is $M^d$ torsion-free, that is, does $k \cdot a = k \cdot b$ for some integer $k > 0$ imply $a = b$?

With the unique representation of $M^2$ above one can show that $M^2$ is indeed both cancellative and torsion-free, but I have no clue for $d > 2$.

It is ccancellative and torsion-free, because it is a quotient of free commutative monoid (which is graded by total length of an element) by a system of homogeneous relations, so grading descends to the quotient.

@DenisT I don’t understand your argument, if I quotient the free commutative monoid on generators $a,b,c$ by the relation $a+b=a+c$ then the result is obviously not cancellative.
